# Use Dart Sass modules in Next.js

Tags: sass, next.js

I want to support multiple Sass files with Next.js (v10.0.9).

Following the [directions](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support), I've installed `sass` (v1.32.8, under `devDependencies`).

styles/globals.scss works fine, imported into pages/_app.tsx with `import '../styles/globals.scss';`.

However, if I add styles/colors.scss containing `$base-color: darkblue;` and attempt to use it in globals.scss as follows:

```
@use 'colors';

body {
  color: $base-color;
}
```

`yarn dev` reports:

> error - ./styles/globals.scss ((webpack)/css-loader/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!(webpack)/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-2!(webpack)/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!(webpack)/sass-loader/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./styles/globals.scss)
>
> SassError: Undefined variable.
>
> 4 │   color: $base-color;

I've tried adding `sassOptions` with `includePaths` in next.config.js, changing the `@use` path, etc. without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a huddle using `@use`.

The idea btw. the new technique of `@use` (and the upcomming way to write SASS in the future as `@import` is deprecated) is, that members (vars, funcs, mixs) ARE ALLWAYS SET TO A SEPERATED NAMESPACE when they are '@used`.

So, if you `@use` a file with variables the variables are provided to a seperate namespace which is the name of the file. That means: if you are working with them you need to call them by `filename.varibale`.

If you want to use the variables with another (or no additional) namespace you need explicite to notice that to the '@use-rule'.

To your example that means:

```
// simple @use a file 
// --> then call members (vars, funcs, mixs) with namespace
// namespace = name of file where variables come from

@use 'colors';

body {
  color: colors.$base-color;
}


// @use file and set namespace 
// --> call members with this namespace
//
// ### Note the intended advantage: 
// In this case you are able to work in the var file without prefixes/suffix
// Variables conflicts with different (external!) modules can be handled 
// or do not arise at all this way

@use 'colors' as color;
// color vars in file 'colors' now can be: 
// $base, $primary, $red, $green, ... only

body {
  color: color.$base;
}


// @use a file without adding a namespace
// --> you can call variables the traditional way as set in the file
// in this (by the developer of SASS NOT intended) case advice namespace as '*'

@use 'colors' as *;

body {
  color: $base-color;
}
```

More information: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: Serves me right for not reading the rest of the documentation! Works perfectly!